# aws s3 csv upload from ai2 using post text and presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, app-inventor

I am exhausted looking for the solution in the google forum, Stack and AWS help and thus posting a new question.

I have a webservice through which I am generating a presigned POST url for my s3 bucket. I have tested it with python request.post module and it works just fine.

all I'm trying to upload are simple small csv string data. e.g. "a,1,b,2,c,3"

[image]

incase the image above is not readable : it looks like this:

> url,https://genome-analytics-scratch-space.s3.amazonaws.com/;;AWSAccessKeyId,AKZZZZZZZZZZQ;;ContentType,multipart/form-data;;acl,public-read;;key,slaik/somejson.json;;signature,+IZZZZZZZZZZZZZZM=;;policy,eyZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZJ9;;x-amz-server-side-encryption,AES256;;

I have an absolutely simple ai2 app with just 1 button, 1 web component and a label to show the output.
[image]

The block i have designed looks like this.[image]

The output I'm getting is :[image]

I have tried setting my fields & conditions values to for the presigned POST url as mentioned below.

```
fields = {"acl": "public-read",
        "ContentType": "multipart/form-data",
        "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"}

# Ensure that the ACL isn't changed and restrict the user to a length
# between 10 and 100.
conditions = [
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    ["content-length-range", 0, 10485760],
    {"ContentType": "multipart/form-data"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"}
```

I have also tried setting content type to text/csv. But all I'm getting is this same error and I have written so much code for the download and other features, a lot is hanging on cracking this for me.

Any guidance, observation, link, clues would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: multipart/formdata is not supported in App Inventor...

Comment: @Taifun if anyone can come up with an extension to handle this .. it's gotta be you. :)